# stock prediction python SVR syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to do the stock prediction using `SVR` and here's the code that I'm using:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dates = []
prices = []
def get_data(filename):
    with open (filename,'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('-')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
        return
def predict_prices(dates,prices,x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates,(len(dates),1)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates, prices)

    plt.scatter(dates, prices, color='balck',lable = 'Data')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_rbf.predict(dates),color = 'red',lable = 'rbf' )
    plt.plot(dates,svr_poly.predict(dates),color = 'blue',lable = 'poly' )
    plt.plot(dates,svr_lin.predict(dates),color = 'green',lable = 'lin' )
    plt.xlabel('date')
    plt.ylabel('price')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0]

get_data('data1.csv')
predicted_price = predict_price(dates,prices,29)
print(predicted_price)
```

The above codes give the following error:

```
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not know why there is a syntax error. I also changed `C=1e6` then to success.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing `)` on line 16. This kind of thing can confuse the Python interpreter, which sometimes indicates the error occurs on the following line (as you experienced).

To fix this, just change:

```
dates = np.reshape(dates,(len(dates),1)
```

to:

```
dates = np.reshape(dates, (len(dates),1))
```

Comment: Are you sure about this change? The third argument should be a string: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Whoops, fixed. The second argument should be a tuple

Comment: raise ValueError("'color' kwarg must be an mpl color"

the problem is solved there is no syntax error now thanks a lot but here I m facing a new error. ValueError: 'color' kwarg must be an mpl color spec or sequence of color specs.
For a sequence of values to be color-mapped, use the 'c' kwarg instead.even after changing color to c and writing initials of color-red as 'r' no success. please help.

Comment: @Anisha that sounds like another question -- the StackOverflow community likes folks to post a new question so that others will be able to search for exactly your new question in the future...